# Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: notebook - Warning in Jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, backend

I want to use the interactive plots in jupyter, but when switching the backend to notebook, I get the warning:
Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: notebook. Using qt5 instead.

This happens on Windows 10, Anaconda 1.8.7, jupyter 5.5.0, python 3.6.5 and matplotlib 2.2.2.

Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
```

Output:

```
Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: notebook. Using qt5 instead.
```

I found some question here where the problem is the other way around, but could not find anyone having this problem yet.
In some cases, importing ipympl is mentioned as a solution, but this does not change anything in my case.

Any hints?

Comment: Does the same happen when inverting the order of the commands? First, `%matplotlib ...` then `import ...`?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I just found out that the notebook backend is not registered in matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends: 
`matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends: 

    ['GTK',  'GTKAgg',  'GTKCairo',  'GTK3Agg',  'GTK3Cairo',  'MacOSX',
     'nbAgg',  'Qt4Agg',  'Qt4Cairo',  'Qt5Agg',  'Qt5Cairo',  'TkAgg',  'TkCairo',
     'WebAgg',  'WX',  'WXAgg',  'WXCairo',  'agg',  'cairo',  'gdk',  'pdf',  'pgf',
     'ps',  'svg',  'template']`

Comment: Well, it's called  `'nbAgg'` here. But I think this list would even list backends, if they were not available at all.

Comment: I don't have your exact versions (also jupyter consists of several parts, not sure what (5.5.0) refers to) but at least in my setup I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: And you also have Win10 and Anaconda? I never had the problem in Ubuntu, but it seems like this only occurs in Win10.

Comment: I have windows 8.1 and miniconda, but I don't think its system dependent at all. It's rather some issue with the exact versions in use, I suppose.

Comment: Hmm... Now I created an environment with Python 3.7.0, Jupyter notebook server 5.7.0, ipython 6.5.0 and matplotlib 3.0.0 - and the problem still persists.

Comment: So there is [no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FttYw.png) when not setting any backend beforehands for me. Your problem can be reproduced when [explicitely setting a backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnBPV.png). This means somewhere in your configuration the backend is already set to qt.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this pointed me in the right direction to fix the problem! I will give it a try and write the answer myself now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) pointed out in the comments, my problem was related to the backend already being set when jupyter starts. However, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939989/matplotlib-configuration-for-inline-backend-in-jupyter-notebook), the backend needs to be set in the `ipython_config.py`, not the `jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

After restarting the notebook server, I can switch between backends as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545050/using-matplotlib-notebook-after-matplotlib-inline-in-jupyter-notebook-doesnt).

Comment: Where to find this `ipython_config.py`?

Comment: It is either in `~/.ipython/`. But if you run jupyter from a virtual env you may search into the path where the environment is stored

Answer (score 7):

You must put `%matplotlib widget` in the very beginning of the Jupyterlab