# Matplotlib magic in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, data-science

When i am using the magic `%matplotlib notebook` it shows the follwing warning:`Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: notebook. Using gtk3 instead.`
What is the reason for this warning and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Have considered the other answers given to that question, i.e., [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703190/cannot-change-to-a-different-gui-toolkit-notebook-warning-in-jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703190/cannot-change-to-a-different-gui-toolkit-notebook-warning-in-jupyter), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939989/matplotlib-configuration-for-inline-backend-in-jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939989/matplotlib-configuration-for-inline-backend-in-jupyter-notebook), [github - issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11365)